# Search two lines continuously in notepad++

Tags: linux, bash, shell, notepad++

i have a file like this

```
number 1
number 2
number 3

number 4
number 5

number 6
number 7

number 8
number 9
number 9
```

i want to export or search all two lines continuously ,my result i hope is

```
number 4
number 5

number 6
number 7
```

i use notepad++ or bash linux command.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? If so, please edit your post and paste a code snippet there.

Comment: yes ,i try ,but it seems i can not solve it ,dear

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a challenge since everything is designed to work on one line at a time.  Also, you have to deal with overlapping strings along with start & end fencepost cases.  I don't know how large your file is, so slurping everything in at once and using it as one big string might not be feasible.  But for small data sets, with a suitably recent version of perl, you might try:

```
perl -n0e 'while ( /(?=((^|\n) *\n(.+\n.+\n)( *\n|$)))/gi ) { print "$3\n"; }' datafile
```

Basically, match:

```
"(^|\n)"     Beginning of file (string) or prior line's newline.
" *\n"       A blank line.
"(.+\n"      First line with data, paren starts data we will extract.
".+\n)"      Second line with data, paren ends data we will extract.
"( *\n|$)"   A blank line or end of file (string).

/(?=())/gi   Matches overlapping strings, case ignored, all strings.

-e  Following argument is a one-line program.
-n  Assume while(<>) around program.
-0  Slurp entire argument (datafile) as single string.
```

For larger files you would be better off with a finite state machine.  This is not particularly pretty.  It's been a while since I've worked in awk.  But it will suffice:

```
awk '
function printLines() { if ( i == 2 )  { print line[0]"\n"line[1]"\n"; } }
function zeroLines()  { i=0; line[0]=""; line[1]=""; }
BEGIN   { zeroLines() }
/^ *$/  { printLines(); zeroLines(); } # Matches blank line
/^ *./  { if ( i < 2 ) { line[i] = $0; } i++; } # Matches non-blank line
END     { printLines() }
' < datafile
```

Comment: Thanks much for the 2nd solution ,dear ,but the first solution `perl -n0e 'while ( /(?=((^|\n) *\n(.+\n.+\n)( *\n|$)))/gi ) { print "$3\n"; }' datafile` does not work .

Comment: What version of perl do you have?  (perl --version)  I verified it works on perl 5.12, and that it will not work on 5.8.  (It's the lookahead to deal with overlapping strings bit.)  Also, in hindsight, perl should be using something like "( *.+\n" and " *.+\n)" to avoid blank lines being seen as data lines.

Comment: Correction:  Use something like "( *\S.*\n" and " *\S.*\n)" to avoid blank lines (lines with only whitespace) from being seen as data lines.  E.g.:  perl -n0e 'while ( /(?=((^|\n) *\n( *\S.*\n *\S.*\n)( *\n|$)))/gi ) { print "$3\n"; }' datafile

Comment: This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int
(with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)